# Mesa or Mali is in use?

Tags: opengl-es, mesa, mali

I have a embedded system which's GPU is mali T624.
I have glmark2 and glmark2-es2, 
when running glmark2, information shows mesa software render
when running glmark2-es2, info shows T624 openGL ES 3.1

My question is, if I have QT demos which need openGL acceleration, 
how can I know whether Mesa software render or Mali HW render in use?
and how can I manually switch in between?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The glmark benchmark comes in two flavors.

- The `glmark2` binary uses the full OpenGL backend
- The `glmark2-es2` binary uses the OpenGL ES backend

Mali only supports OpenGL ES; it doesn't ship with a full desktop OpenGL driver.

In terms of "is Mali being used" you can install the DS-5 Streamline profiler - Community Edition is free - which will let you determine if there is any GPU activity in the system.